# Import '<match_id>' only when the '<game>' contains '<lineup1>' and the '<source>' is 'soccerway'

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In this `<game>` contains `<lineup1>`, I would like to collect the `<match_id>` only when there is `<lineup1>` inside `<game>` and the `<source>` is `soccerway`

[image]

And this game not contains the details:

[image]

Formula I tried to use:

```
=IMPORTXML("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","//match_id[contains(//game,'lineup1') and contains(//source,'soccerway')]")
```

Which Xpath should I use? In the format I tried to use it returned all `<match_id>` without filtering.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the actual html (not an image) or the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this xpath expression

```
=IMPORTXML("XXXXXXX","//game[source='soccerway'][lineup1]/match_id/text()")
```

should output

```
3406369
3361952
3287901
```

Comment: Thank you very much @JackFleeting, that was exactly my need. I ask you to edit the answer and put XXXXX in place of the link please, this API has limitations and if it is exposed it hinders the sales of the site.